# how to prevent lstlisting from reseting \everypar?

Tags: listings, paragraphs

As I noticed lstlisting reset \everypar by {}! so previous \everypar has no effect after lstlisting. 
How to prevent lstlisting environment from reseting \everypar? in other words, I want to set an \everypar that works throughly in the text.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\everypar{\lq\lq{}EVERYPAR\rq\rq}

\lipsum[1-2]


\hrule 
\begin{lstlisting}
Listing Environment
\end{lstlisting}
\hrule 

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: lstlisting like almost all latex displays is a list and lists and section headings reset everypar to control indentation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this isn't really safe and may not do quite what you want, but it does do what you asked for,

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\let\oldeverypar\everypar
\newtoks\everypar
\oldeverypar{\the\everypar\lq\lq{}EVERYPAR\rq\rq}


\lipsum[1-2]


\hrule 
\begin{lstlisting}
Listing Environment
\end{lstlisting}
\hrule 

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for this answer... and particularly for the first sentence! ;-)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question in my opinion. The OP is interested in the output as-is from the `lstlisting` environment, but would like `\everypar` to continue as before `lstlisting`.

Comment: @Werner sure but the question isn't really clear about exactly when the modified everypar is supposed to act (eg the example provided doesn't have section headings or a center environment etc) I could make listings "safe" but I doubt that would really be any better. If the question is clarified for real intent the real answer may not involve \everypar at all (despite the question title)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle
this solution affects all latex display even section!
I wanted to set a special charachter at the begining of each paragraph of the text by \everypar but lstlisting and even section or something like that will reset it. 
Suppose I want to count all paragraphs in a text with the aid of \everypar. I want to know is it possible or not? something like a linenumber that listings uses for counting its lines but in my case for counting all paragraphs of a text.

Comment: @javadr that was the point of my answer `\everypar` is a low level command that affects every low level paragraph that includes section headings, individual lines forced by `\\ ` in center and similar environments and lots of other places. It is probably not the tool you need, but really you only asked about `\everypar` you haven#t given a clear indication intention of the final formatting (which may for example be best done as a list with your text added by `\item`)

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\everypar{\lq\lq{}EVERYPAR\rq\rq}

\lipsum[1-2]


\hrule\begingroup
\begin{lstlisting}
Listing Environment
\end{lstlisting}
\endgroup\hrule 

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{listings}

\newtoks\myeverypar
\begin{document}
\everypar{\lq\lq{}EVERYPAR\rq\rq}

\lipsum[1-2]


\hrule\begingroup
\begin{lstlisting}
Listing Environment
\end{lstlisting}
\global\myeverypar\expandafter{\the\everypar}\endgroup
\everypar\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\the
\expandafter\myeverypar\expandafter\everypar\expandafter{\the\everypar}}\hrule 

\lipsum[3-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{listings}

\newtoks\myeverypar
\begin{document}
\everypar{\lq\lq{}EVERYPAR\rq\rq}

\lipsum[1-2]

\makeatletter

\hrule\myeverypar\expandafter{\the\everypar}%
\begin{lstlisting}
Listing Environment
\end{lstlisting}
\def\par {\@restorepar \clubpenalty \@clubpenalty \everypar
\expandafter{\the\myeverypar}\par \@endpefalse}\hrule

\lipsum[3-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yes but that also stops the the \everpar setting that listings set to work, so you lose control over indentation (not obvious in this example)  add `\section{kkkk} kkkkk` for example.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle see update. Actually I don't exactly know what the OP is after.

Comment: probably not `\everypar` :-)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest defining your own listings environment via `\lstnewenvironment`. This allows some hooks that might be of interest:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{listings,everyhook}

\lstnewenvironment{mylstlisting}[1][]
  {\SavePreHook{par}{\prelistingpar}%
   \ClearPreHook{par}\endgraf
   \noindent\rule{\linewidth}{.4pt}%
   \lstset{#1}}
  {\endgraf\noindent\rule[.5\baselineskip]{\linewidth}{.4pt}%
   \RestorePreHook{par}{\prelistingpar}}

\begin{document}

\PushPreHook{par}{``EVERYPAR''}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{mylstlisting}
Listing Environment
\end{mylstlisting}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: this makes listings sort of safe but add `\section{kkkk}kkk` and EVERYPAR shows up (presumably unwanted) in the section heading, so unless you redefine _everything_ it doesn't really help.